# Create a column whose value is the sum of the value of the neighbouring polygons

Tags: python, r, gis, shapefile, qgis

I have some shapefiles with municipal areas of Spain that contain, besides the identifiers of each area, the number of irrigated hectares.
My goal is to create a column whose value is the sum of irrigated hectares of the neighbouring polygons for each municipal area.
For instance, in the image below, the middle polygon would have a value with the sum of the yellow (selected) irrigate ha.

[image]

The shp files attribute table looks like this:

| Identitycode | area_name | irrigated_ha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01234 | Madrid | 234.56 |
| 023453 | Manresa | 120.45 |

The resulting data should look something like this:

| Identitycode | area_name | irrigated_ha | neighbour_ha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01234 | Madrid | 234.56 | 435.34 |
| 023453 | Manresa | 120.45 | 234.98 |

Any help / solution is more than welcome, especially with QGIS or R.

Best regards to all and thank you in advance.

Comment: hard to answer without proper sample data.in `R`,  I'd suggest the `st_touches`-function of the `sf`-package as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use field calculator in QGIS 3.16.
You have to create a new field **neighbour_ha** and then use this formula

```
aggregate( 
    layer:='name layer with polygon',   
    aggregate:='sum',   
    expression:= "irrigated_ha",
    filter:=   touches($geometry,geometry(@parent))
    )
```

The formula adds field **irrigate_ha** values, only for those features that **touch** the current feature.

If some features would not token in cosideration, you can use intersects() function instead of touches()

Answer (score 0):

With Python and geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd 

df = gpd.read_file('shapefile.shp')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    neighbors = df[df.geometry.touches(row['geometry'])].Identitycode.tolist()
    #neighbors = neighbors.remove(row.Identitycode)
    # You can use list comprehension to exclude the current row in area sum
    neighbors = [id for id in neighbors if row.Identitycode != id]

    area = df[df.Identitycode.isin(neighbors)]['irrigated_ha'].sum()
    df.at[index, "neighbour_ha"] = area
```